# DropDownList for referenced values - on Post: Create - NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-3

On the SaveChanges i get an NullReferenceException.

This is my DropDownList in my view:

@Html.DropDownList("MaterialCategory.Id", Model.Categorieën)

The selected value is inserted in : 
MaterialDetail.MaterialCategory.Id , but all the other values are not inserted (eg. name and description of the Category).

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(db.MaterialDetail materiaal_detail)
    {
        try
        {
         //   TryUpdateModel<db.MaterialDetail>(materiaal_detail); ???
           materiaal_detail.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

In short, i receive the selected id but can't seem to save it to the database.
The problem has to be somewhere in the entities.

MaterialDetail => OK
MaterialCategory, has the id and i thought when i'd save it, it would only insert the appropriate GUID in the MaterialDetail.CategoryId. But this ain't happening.

And this is my Create (View)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>MaterialDetail</legend>


    <div class="editor-label">
        Category
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("MaterialCategory.Id", Model.Categorieën)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Materiaal.name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Materiaal.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Materiaal.name)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Materiaal.description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Materiaal.description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Materiaal.description)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Materiaal.inStock)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Materiaal.inStock)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Materiaal.inStock)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
   </fieldset>
```

The Guid is inserted in the MaterialCategory.Id
How can i solve this?

Comment: Off-topic: In most RDBMS using a GUID for a primary key is usually a less-than-optimal solution. See http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx

Comment: Where in the HTML/View does the user enter the name and description of the new Category? Which line/variable of code is throwing the NullReferenceException? What data-access/ORM framework/library are you using? If it's a problem, with the model instance not getting filled with values, which values are missing and what is the code in the HTML/View that you think is populating those values but isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your input fields will be prefixed with `Materiaal` except the dropdownlist where you have hardcoded it. So you might need to specify this prefix if you want the model binder to be able to properly assign the values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "Materiaal")]db.MaterialDetail materiaal_detail)
{
    ...
}
```

or use the top level model (the one that contains the `Materiaal`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SomeModel model)
{
    db.MaterialDetail m = model.Materiaal;
    ...
}
```

Also I feel obligated to point out that using your EF models into the views is BAD practice. I would recommend you design view models which are classes specifically tailored to the needs of the view and contain only the properties necessary for this view. To facilitate the mapping between the models and the view models you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

So here are two scenarios:

1. The controller queries a repository and fetches a model. The controller maps this model into a view model and passes the view model to the view
2. The controller receives a view model (as argument) from the view. The controller maps the view model to the corresponding model. The controller calls a repository method to update something passing it the model.

Comment: I almost have it.
I only need to know now how i can bind:
MaterialCategory.Id to my model (it's a Guid).

In short, MaterialDetails properties are retrieved.
But i need to bind the MaterialCategory.Id to the MaterialDetails properties.


I know that (for now), that there are better practises, but i'm starting to understand the ASP.Net MVC framework better. So for now, i only care about the solution. The right implementation (UnitOfWork and Repositories patterns is the next step ;))